# How do I wrap a Firebase OnCompleteListener with a RxJava Single<>?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase to upload an image. I'm using Firebase's `.onCompleteListener()` to get the URL of the uploaded image in the callback.

I'm trying to incoorporate this into my `Repository` class with a `Single<>`, but I'm unsure how to do it.

Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
public Single<String> uploadImage(String path) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        String fileName = createNewFileName(uri);
        StorageReference ref = firebaseStorage.getReference().child(fileName);

        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(uri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return ref.getDownloadUrl();
            }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    String url = downloadUri.toString();
                    
                    //String to use in Single<>
                } else {
                    //Handle Error
                }
            });
        });

    }
```

[image]

To use in my `ViewModel`

```
uploadImage(path)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(url -> {
                    
        }, err -> {
                    
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Single.create`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Single.html#create-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.SingleOnSubscribe-):

> Provides an API (via a cold Single) that bridges the reactive world with the callback-style world.

```java
return Single.<String>create(emitter -> {
            UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(uri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return ref.getDownloadUrl();
            }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    String url = downloadUri.toString();
                    
                    emitter.onSuccess(url);
                } else {
                    emitter.onError(task.getException());
                }
            });
        });
```